# Set Context.UserIdentifier to different claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

By default, `signalr` sets `Context.UserIdentifier` from `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` in jwt token. 
But I want to set it to different claim from token, which is userId and not username, because when I send message to specific user I have his id available. 
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `IUserIdProvider` and register it.

```
public class CustomUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public virtual string GetUserId(HubConnectionContext connection)
    {
        return connection.User?.FindFirst(yourClaimTypeHere)?.Value;
    }
}

services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, CustomUserIdProvider>();
```

Comment: There's related information at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-claims-to-customize-identity-handling